WiFi connectivity hangs intermittently after upgrading to 24.04
I upgraded to 24.04 from 23.10 last week and have had issues with WiFi since. It works fine most of the time and has no issue connecting to various access points, however after some time the connection will hang completely. The WiFi will still be displayed as connected to the router, but nothing will load and nothing will get pinged either in the terminal. At that point I can just toggle WiFi off and on and it will work again so it's not the worst issue but it's quite inconvenient. Never had WiFi issues on this laptop prior to this.
The time between occurrences is somewhat random, sometimes with hours in-between and sometimes only 15/20 minutes, one trend I'm seeing is it seems to occur primarily during times of sustained downloads (large file downloads, video streaming, ...) but even then the time between issues will vary greatly.
I'm running a Dell XPS 13 2 in 1 (7390) from 2019. The Network controller is displayed as:
Network controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 30)
Subsystem: Rivet Networks Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

I've tried running sudo dmesg and journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager but they don't seem to display anything that could be the cause the issues when they happen, the latter was throwing up some kind of error with a tlp config file (but not just when the issue occurred) but uninstalling tlp hasn't changed anything besides removing that error message.
Would appreciate any advice on diagnosing the issue, or pointers towards a relevant bug tracker or fix.
Thanks in advance !
Edit: Added result of apt policy tlp-rdw power-profiles-daemon
    tlp-rdw:
  Installé : (aucun)
  Candidat : 1.6.1-1ubuntu1
 Table de version :
     1.6.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
power-profiles-daemon:
  Installé : 0.21-1
  Candidat : 0.21-1
 Table de version :
 *** 0.21-1 500
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Per advice gotten on the #ubuntu IRC channel, I've also tried to add options iwlmvm power_scheme=1 to my iwlwifi.conf file, however it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.
Edit 2: Added results of journalctl --grep='wifi|iwlwifi|networkmanager|wireless|iwlmvm' --since='-10min' --no-pager right after the issue occurred to this paste. Some more context, I had to re-run it a few times because at the exact time of crash the output of the command was nothing, and this time around the internet connection came back on without me having to turn it on and off (which hadn't happened before).
On the other hand, sudo dmesg | grep -i iwlwifi didn't return anything around the time of the issue or even a bit after.

Please, include the output of apt policy tlp-rdw power-profiles-daemon in your question.

I've added the output of that command as well as another bit of information on something I have tried.

Thanks, please wait for that issue (WIFI hang) to happen and immediately run journalctl --grep='wifi|iwlwifi|networkmanager|wireless|iwlmvm' --since='-10min' --no-pager and include its output in your question or link to it if it's too big to fit in the question.

And can also add sudo dmesg | grep -i iwlwifi please? Maybe firmware problem.

Added that ouput as well as a bit of context with the latest crash. I've also only had the crash once in the past day (which is less than usual, but then again the time between hangs seems completely random since the beginning) which is why this took a while.

strange nothing in dmesg. Is package linux-firmware on your system?

I have that package installed, yes. To be clear when I say nothing in the dmesg output I mean nothing relevant around the time of crash, just some stuff around boot time.

can you add this too? The stuff from boot time please.

There you go: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bXtfhsvjxt/

Your log shows clearly: Failed to query location: No WiFi networks found. Maybe a driver problem?. Download a manjaro (which is not a Debian derivative) and check with live usb if your wifi works there

Please if present remove package backport-iwlwifi-dkms. Create file /etc/modprobe.d/own-iwlwifi.conf with following content. options  bt_coex_active=disable enable_ini=false 11n_disable=2 remove_when_gone=1 reboot; after it hangs again control journalctl -b | grep -i firmware if a firmware is crashing in background.
